# Gatling: Producer and consumer users

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a load test where three sets of users create something and a different set of users perform some actions on them.

What is the recommended way to co-ordinate this behaviour in Gatling?

I'm currently using an `object` which contains a `LinkedBlockingQueue` which the "producers" `put` the ID and consumers `take`, see below.

However, it causes the test to hang after ~20s (targeting 1tps).
I've also tried using `poll` with a timeout, but instead of hanging the poll almost always fails (after 30s) or causes a hang if the timeout is larger (1m+).

This seems to be because all the threads are blocked waiting for something from the queue so isn't compatible with the way Gatling tests run (i.e. not 1 thread per user). Is there a non-blocking way to wait in the Gatling DSL?

Producer.scala

```
// ...
scenario("Produce stuff")
    .exec(/* HTTP call which extracts an ID*/)
    .exec(session => Queue.ids.put(session("my-id").as[String])
// ...
```

Consumer.scala

```
// ...
scenario("Consume stuff")
    .exec(session => session.set("my-id", Queue.ids.take()))
    .exec(/* HTTP call which users ID*/)
// ...
```

Queue.scala

```
object Queue {
    val ids = new LinkedBlockingQueue[String]()
}
```

As an alternative I've tried to use the application functionality but it seems a harder problem to ensure that each user picks a unique item from the app.

Comment: I've solved it for my use-case by staggering the injection of the consumers so they don't have to wait on an empty queue; but it would be good to know a better solution.

Comment: why not combine the producer and consumer scenarios into one with a random pause in between? eg: `scenario("produceAndConsume").exec(produceStuff).pause(10 seconds, 60 seconds).exec(consumeStuff)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I should have stated (but wanted to keep the question simple) that there are 3 different producer journeys and one consumer and they have different login details.

Comment: I see - having different users communicate within the same simulation is not really how gatling is designed (though as you've discovered, you can kludge it). I'd either find a way to push the scenarios together using a switch or similar to have different producers, or have  a simulation for producers that writes to a csv file with a separate simulation that consumes from that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acknowledging this is all a hack, my current solution in `Consumer.scala` is:

```scala
doIf(_ =>  Queue.ids.size() < MIN_COUNT)(
  pause(30) // wait for 30s if queue is initially too small
)
.doWhile(_ => Queue.ids.size() >= MIN_COUNT)(
  exec(session => session.set("my-id", Queue.ids.take()))
    .exec(...)
    .pause(30)
)
```